# How do I allow my program to detect keyCode without getting a type-error in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typeerror, keycode

I am fairly new to coding and I have been constantly been coming upon one problem. When making a game, such as snake or pong, I tend to use an event listener to listen for a keydown event such as : `document.body.addEventListener("keydown", moveSnake);`. I then go onto declare the function moveSnake :

```js
function moveSnake(event){
    switch(event.keyCode){
        case 87:
             break;
        case 83:
             break;
        case 65:
            break;
        case 68:
            break;
         default:
             break;
    }
}
```

I understand there is no code telling the snake what to do yet. Once I do this I get a reoccurring issue. My program stops, and I get an error message in my console that says : `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'keyCode')`. I am using the latest version of google chrome and if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong it would be much appreciated. I have tried declaring the keyCode as a variable, and many other suggestions I have found randomly online but nothing as worked. Thank you!

Comment: Have a read of this: [Create a Minimal Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That does not seem possible with that code.

Comment: Agreed with @epascarello. This code is valid. There must be another factor we are unaware of.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The .keyCode has been deprecated due to inconsistency on browsers. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

You can try with the .code, which names the keys as "ArrowUp", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight" and "ArrowDown".

Comment: Not sure how this is the accepted answer since "event being undefined" has nothing to do with keyCode being deprecated.

Comment: I never was really sure what deprececated meant to the link provided was helpful. I used some things off of the site and tested out the .code and I found some success. Ultimately,  I ended up using an arrow function expression in the event listener and I encapsulated the whole event listener in a moveSnake function.